# Spring security for Authorization only

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm working in a new project where I need to manage user roles, just that, because this application is using its own authentication system through web services. So, the only thing I need to do is validate each user role, if the user id exists in my database he could enter otherwise will be rejected. It means, no password, no login page (that is performed by the web services), just user id validation and get their roles.

I did a proof of concept in order to implement this according to my understanding, this was after reading the documentation involved. The point is that this is not working as expected, let me share this example with you:

Security settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
<security:anonymous enabled="false" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="home.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="excel.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"   />
<security:intercept-url pattern="denied.jsp" access="permitAll" />
<security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="meivFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<bean id="meivFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="Host" />
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="preauthAuthProvider"
class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.
preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
<property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
    <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.gm.gpsc.meiv.security.UserServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

Note:In order to test it, as you can see, I use in RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter as principalRequestHeader attribute, the Host header value which is present as default header value. Just for testing. Because in the future I going to read a value from the header.

This is the userDetailService I did in order to get user roles.

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

private boolean accountNonExpired = true;
private boolean accountNonLocked = true;
private boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
private boolean enabled = true;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
     GrantedAuthority[] grantedAuthority = new GrantedAuthority[1];  
     grantedAuthority[0] = new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER");
     Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(); 
     authorities.add(grantedAuthority[0]);

    return new User(userId, "x",enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);          
}
```

}

When I run this example the settings are loaded successfully, then when I try to reach the first pattern, home.html, I can reach that page, which is wrong, because according to my rule I have ROLE_USER and as you can see above I need ROLE_ADMIN.

For the second pattern I could get access too but in that case it makes sense because ROLE_USER is include as rule.

For the first situation I change home.html for /home.html and I got 403 Access denied. But If I use the same pattern for the second option excel, it means /excel.html, I got the same error (403).

This is the error I get from the log file:

```
DEBUG | 2012-09-30 03:55:09,738 | FilterChainProxy | /index.jsp at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG | 2012-09-30 03:55:09,739 | HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository | No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG | 2012-09-30 03:55:09,739 | HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG | 2012-09-30 03:55:09,744 | FilterChainProxy | /index.jsp at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG | 2012-09-30 03:55:09,744 | RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter | Checking secure context token: null
DEBUG | 2012-09-30 03:55:09,744 | HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG | 2012-09-30 03:55:09,744 | SecurityContextPersistenceFilter | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
30/09/2012 03:55:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet jsp lanzó excepción
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException: MYID header not found in request.
```

I don't understand what's going on here, maybe someone can explain me where I'm wrong.

I'd appreciate your help because I am so confused with this and tired of reading the documentation without getting anywhere.

Comment: have you tried to implement your own authentication provider?

Comment: Check the debug log. In each case it will spell out how a request is matched and why access is either granted or denied. And you're correct, you should use "/home.html" rather than "home.html". Again the logging is very clear about how it matches incoming requests so you should see which pattern is being used for a request.

Comment: Thank you Luke for clarifying it, I'm going to debug it and I'll let you know.

Comment: I realized something else, this is regarding principalRequestHeader attribute, in RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter class.

The point is, when I deploy my application, when the context is loading, this is looking for that attribute and I get   
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException: USER_ID header not found in request. The authentication did not happen, Why it is reading the header?
Why do I get this error? if the authentication is not performed yet, I mean how should it work?

Thanks in advance, 

Luis.

Comment: @LukeTaylor, below I added the log I get every time I'm trying to start the application. I mean, when I perform tomcat start after deploy my application, I get this error.

Comment: Please read the Javadoc for [RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.html). It explains very clearly what it does. It reads the header to obtain the username and throws an exception if it's not found.

Comment: @LukeTaylor thanks for replying it. I read the API, but I don't understand what is going on in this particular situation, because I get the error when the application is loading its context. No one attempt to access it, that's why there is no value in the header. According to the documentation (Pre-Authentication Scenarios) it should be used when we need to implement external authentication systems. In my case I'm going to receive from an external system a value in the header. I'd like someone can tell me what's missing here because I cannot realized. Or maybe this is not the way to solve it.

Comment: I don't believe it happens during context loading. That should also be obvious from the debug log and also the stacktrace which will include tomcat classes. There's clearly a request for `index.jsp`. Where could that have come from unless something accessed the application.

Comment: @LukeTaylor You are right, thanks!. It was my mistake I did not realize that. Now, I'm trying to test it, I created an application in order to add an attribute in the header and test the pre-Authentication. But it does not work, it is difficult too. Anyway, that's another issue!